Code that has been working for months now gives this error in several different macros - VBA Run-time error -214724809 (80070057): Invalid Argument
Is there something that can cause this error to start happening out of no where?  Why would code that I have ran hundreds of times all of a sudden start to show this, and its not just one macro, but multiple.  I cant see any reason that it would have started, nothing seems off with any of the code, especially considering it had been working.
The error is on Rows(lrow).copy
Worksheets("Master").Activate
For lRow = (ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - (15)) To 3 Step -1 ' Finds the last row in order to dynamically insert the rows
    If Cells(lRow, "B") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "B") Then
    Rows(lRow).Copy
    Rows(lRow).Resize(j - 1).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrbelow
    End If
Next lRow


Have you updated anything?

Can you post an example code? On which line do you get this error?

I have posted the code, and I have updated other macros.  I dont see how that could affect other code though, no updates to the macros now causing this error.

It might not fix your issue, but it would be wise to qualify your Cells and Rows - i.e. use ws.Cells(lRow, "B"), ws.Rows(lRow).Copy and ws.Rows(lRow).Resize(......

I was just thinking about that actually, I will make the adjustment and see what happens.  I will report back in a bit.

My first guess is that lrow becomes negative at some point :-)

How is lRow defined? Is it of type Long as the name implies?

A negative lRow would throw a 1004, not what OP is seeing, @Dominique.

So I took CLR's suggestion, adding the declared ws. in front of the Rows fixed the issue.  lrow is defined as Long for those asking.  But I find it odd, the code worked as it was for so long, why would it have stopped and required the ws in front of the rows and cells?

Without the qualification, you're relying on Excel choosing the right worksheet/book every time. Perhaps something in the background is changing the active sheet/book while the code is running, causing issues..?

@CLR every single time for years and years!! Qualify your ranges and sheets or else something weird will happen.

What is ws and j?

ws was the activeworksheet variable name.  j was the declared variable for the number they input in a userform

You should fully qualify your Rows() statements too.
Also, is is ws = Worksheets("Master")?
Many range operations in Excel can fail if not done on the active sheet.
